# How Can make Toast.makeText in Google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-toast

I want to know how can make 'Toast.makeText`to tell me the order of the cities  in the path

code :

```
        shortest = TSP.tsp(Matrix);


        for(int i=0; i < 20 ; i++)
        {

            googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                            .add(new                   LatLng(placeLatitude[shortest[i]],placeLongitude[shortest[i]]))
                            .add(new LatLng(placeLatitude[shortest[i+1]],placeLongitude[shortest[i+1]]))
            );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please consider putting a minimal code example for your problem, and refocussing your question on your problem, people don't need to know what is the purpose of your application for answering, only that you need to display a `toast` over a google map overlay, the code you provided to assist you is way too long !

Comment: Do you have  experience in the  google map in  Android @dvhh

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) is full description on toast. And I'm guessing you can record the cities being added in order in a String array and run a for loop to append it to your text to be displayed on toast message.